# Integrate XMPP Openfire STUN server with client side js web application

Tags: webrtc, xmpp, openfire, stun, videochat

I have the Openfire server on local machine and I need to use as a server for my video calling web application for that I need Js library to integrate with Web application i.e. Client side. So which one i should use and can get documentation for that.

I tried with Strope.js library in CDN format but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For starters, OpenFire is a signaling server, not a stun server. You might want to check https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-pade-plugin